# What are "4 possible cases for primal and dual linear programming problems"?

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems, operations-research

I am studying for my Linear Programming exam. One of the questions is "*4 possible cases for primal and dual linear programming problems*"? Neither of my mates knows what it is about. We've send an email to our lecturer but haven't recieved an answer. I also surfed the net but in vain. May be you know what could this question be about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quoted phrase is not a question, but I suspect it might be referring to the possible combinations of optimal/infeasible/unbounded for primal and dual problems.  Only 4 of the 9 pairs are possible.  See, for example, page 60 of Chvatal's *Linear Programming* (1983).